# trigram similarity in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, trigram

I have a table with two columns, doc-id, and doc-txt.
each cell in doc-txt contains the full text (around 1000 words) of one document and 100k documents are in a table (100k rows).
I have a list of keywords and I want to find the most similar words in doc-txt to each of these keywords.
what is the efficient approach in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Is this one particular human language?  "Most similar word" is a pretty strange requirement. If you have 100 million words, the most similar word in that set to a keyword is generally going to be the keyword itself.

Answer (score 1):

You'd create a GiST index on the column:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON atable USING gist (doc_txt gist_trgm_ops);
```

Now you can perform a similarity search like this:

```
SELECT * FROM atable
ORDER BY doc_txt <<<-> 'keyword' DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This will find the 10 best hits and can be supported by the index.

The `<<<->` operator corresponds to `strict_word_similarity`, and according to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-FUNC-TABLE)

> the `strict_word_similarity` function is useful for finding the similarity to whole words, while `word_similarity` is more suitable for finding the similarity for parts of words.

Comment: each cell of doc-txt contains a list of around 1000 words (each doc is tokenized into the list of words), and I want to find the most similar word from these 1000 words with a specific keyword.

Comment: Then use a different data model, where each word is its own column.